# UIViewControllerContextTransitioning and UINavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

My code :

navigator.m

```
- (void)newPushPage:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush || operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop)
    {
        self.animator = [Animator new]; 
        return self.animator;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

animator.m

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

    }];

}
```

After the pushPage and the screen appears, there is a problem : are visible all the elements that hide in the code and I can see how elements disappear already seeing the screen. It looks unsightly . There is a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside animateTransition (id)transitionContext protocol push and pop transition should has to be handled separately as below.

//1.Settings for the fromVC ..

```
UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
CGRect sourceRect = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];
CGRect finalFrameForVC = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toVC];
```

//2.Insert the toVC view.

```
   if(pushCondition) { 
   UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
    [container insertSubview:toVC.view aboveSubview:fromVC.view];
    toVC.view.alpha = 0.5;
    toVC.view =
} else if (popCondition ){
    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
    toVC.view.frame = finalFrameForVC;
    toVC.view.alpha = 0.5;
    [container addSubview:toVC.view];
    [container sendSubviewToBack:toVC.view];
    UIView *snapShoot = [fromVC.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:false];
}
```

//3.Perform the animation.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
         usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
          initialSpringVelocity:6.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{

                         //Setup the final parameters of views for push  
                         toVC.view // update final view frame
                         toVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
                        //Setup the final parameters of views for pop
                        snapShoot.frame = 
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //When the animation is completed call completeTransition with final push value
                        [snapShoot removeFromSuperview];
                         //When the animation is completed call completeTransition with final push value
                         toVC.view.alpha= 1.0;
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];

                     }];
```

Create enum / flag property inside amimator and set it inside navigation controller delegate.

```
if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush)
{
    self.animator = [Animator new]; 
    self.animator.pushPopAnimation = UINavigationControllerOperationPush;
    return self.animator;
}
```

See the apple documentation of snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates method in code above.